# Using CGContextDrawTiledImage at different zooms causes massive memory growth

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I'm working on app an where there's a view in a zoomable UIScrollView. When the user zooms in or out, I redraw the view that's in the UIScrollView to be nice and sharp. That view has a background image that I draw with CGContextDrawTiledImage.

I noticed that memory usage grows every time I switch to a new zoom level. It looks like CGContextDrawTiledImage keeps a cache somewhere of the image scaled to different sizes. So, If I go from 1.0 to 1.1x zoom, memory use grows. Going back to 1.0 doesn't cause it to grow, but then going to 1.05 and then 1.2 causes it to grow twice. Back to 1.1 and no growth. Of course, the zoom level is under user control so I don't have control over how many zoom levels happen. Right now my background image is kind of massive (512x512), so this causes memory usage to grow *very* quickly. It doesn't show up as a memory leak in Instruments, just additional allocations that never get freed.

I've tried to find a way to free the cache that appears to be being created, but no luck. It doesn't seem to respond to low memory warnings, for example.

I also tried setting the view's backgroundColor to a  UIColor created with colorWithPatternImage, but that doesn't work because I'm doing the scaling by changing the graphics context's CTM, not by setting the view's transform.

Any ideas on how to keep memory usage from blowing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz is apparently keeping some kind of cache with the CGImage every time that I draw it with a different scaling in the graphics context's CTM. To work around that, when I receive a low memory warning, I release the image and then lazily reinitialize it next time I need it. Not perfect, but the best I could find.

I filed a bug with Apple, but no real response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the rectangle you pass to `CGContextDrawTiledImage` instead of (or prior to) changing the context's CTM?

Comment: I just tried it. It has the same effect as described above. Too bad, because it seemed kind of promising.

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading the image? if you are using + imageNamed: then the image loaded is permanently cached by iOS, + imageWithContentsOfFile: is better.

Comment: I'm using the Quartz API to load it with CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider. I ended up tracking down the solution, but didn't get around to posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jacques answer, I found I could clear the cache by simply making a copy of the `CGImageRef` and releasing the old one.  The caches for other scales are not copied to the new ref.

I call this from anywhere I change scale:

```
 /**
 * Switcheroo to persuade CGImage to drop the many megabytes of cache 
 * it creates when changing scale.
 */
- (void)discardRenderedImageCaches {
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreateCopy(renderedImageRef);
    CGImageRef oldImageRef = renderedImageRef;
    renderedImageRef = newImageRef;
    CGImageRelease(oldImageRef);
}
```